Problemas al refrescar código en servidor Apache
A ver si alguien me puede echar una mano con este "problema" que tengo y no sé solucionar. Tengo un servidor Apache en una Raspberry Pi. Mi problema es que al realizar modificaciones en los archivos Javascript o CSS en la web que está en el servidor y volver a cargar la web, me muestra la versión que está en caché y no la versión con las modificaciones. Al cabo de un tiempo, me muestra ya bien la web, pero no sé cómo conseguir que se cargue siempre la última versíon de los ficheros .js y .css

Lo más fácil, a no ser que estés haciendo cambios constantes en los archivos, es que simplemente borres la caché del navegador. Cada navegador tiene una combinación de teclas para recargar descargando la caché directamente, debería funcionarte

Puedes agregar una variable random para que cargue siempre una nueva versión, en el caso de PHP yo uso:
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js?v=<?php echo(rand());?>"></script>

o sea cuando cargas el js le agregas ?v= de esta manera simpre cargara un random distinto.

Lo mejor es que mientras desarrolles vayas acostumbrandote a limpiar la caché de manera manual, en especial para los cambios de javascript y css que quedan siempre en la caché.
Por otro lado, la respuesta de paillao es una manera de forzar al navegador a estar con la versión actualizada.
Pero, en el servidor apache, puedes configurar que ciertos archivos, en este caso css y js, no sean guardados en la caché. Basta en entrar al .htaccess y configurarlo.
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</FilesMatch>

